# Is there a visual studio template for creating client side typescript apps without asp.net et al

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web, client-side

I want to create a client side app  (AKA a website) without server side be it in Node or ASP.net. Right now I do it by creating a ASP.NET and ignoring all the C# and that is problematic.

Comment: A web site is most definitely not a "client side app". You can create a static site that serves SPA pages, if that's what you mean

Comment: I found the HTML site template from an older VS and will work with that. Is there something better?

As to SPA vs a client-side app it seems like a semantic quibble. The browser just happens to a an execution engine running on the client just like Linux or Windows is an environment.

Comment: Well, "website" isn't synonymous for a client side app.  "Client side app" includes apps that don't run in the browser, i.e. on the users computer.  Just say you're creating a website.  Your "AKA" isn't quite accurate or necessary, and only serves to make things less clear.

Comment: @BobFrankston what you call "semantic quibble" is what prevents you from finding a solution. Google searches, marketplace templates, Github repositories are pretty big on semantics - you won't find anything if you search for the wrong keywords.

Comment: @BobFrankston for example, if you really mean **apps**, you should be looking at Apache Cordova. If you mean SPAs served from a static site, you can just create an empty site project and remove all code files. If you intend to deploy a bunch of HTML and Javascript files like people did in the 90s, just copy those files. MHT files were used to bundle such files in the past, but fell out of favour, mainly due to security issues.

Comment: In fact I am using the template cited below -- I'd forgotten about it because I'd used it in the past.

The current term is "Progressive Web Apps".

Starting with asp.net and removing stuff reminds me of the chicken scene in Five Easy Pieces. And Cordova/Phonegap has a lot of mechanism. I'm trying for a lean HTML5/Typescript without unnecessary stuff that I don't fully understand.

As an FYI I just searched and found https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/building-progressive-web-applications-pwa-with-visual-studio-IR and going to continue to search for other templates and ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 used to have a template for an HTML application with TypeScript. For VS2017 you can get it from here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rich-Newman.TypeScriptHTMLApplicationTemplate